# Enumerate all pure sets

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics, open-ended-function, set-theory

In [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory), a set is an unordered group of unique elements. A pure set is either the empty set \$\{\}\$ or a set containing only pure sets, like \$\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\$.

Your challenge is to write a program that enumerates all pure sets, in some order of your choice. Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply - you may:

- Output all pure sets
- Take an integer \$n\$ and output the nth set by your definition
- Take an integer \$n\$ and output the first n sets.

(\$n\$ may be 0 or 1-indexed)

Pure sets may be represented in any reasonable format.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins.

Comment: Presumably you're only interested in enumerating finite pure sets, there being too many infinite ones to be able to enumerate them anyway.

Comment: Related: [Make every fixed list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240962/make-every-fixed-list)

Comment: @VisualMelon What do you mean by that? I see no answers that do that, and they would be invalid. Also, finite pure sets are *definitely* countable.

Comment: @emanresuA You need to specify in your question that only the recursively finite pure sets should be enumerated. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set).

Comment: @Tyilo I think that's obvious.

Answer (score 18):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 43 bytes

```
f=lambda x:[f(i)for i in range(x)if x>>i&1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3tdNscxJzk1ISFSqsotM0MjXT8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzUqNDPTFCrs7DLVDGMhWnZn2hpwlWdk5qRGFxRl5pVogHRpxlplatsaQlTADAcA)

Outputs the \$ n \$th set, starting at \$ 0 \$.

One way of creating a sequence of all pure sets is to encode them as binary numbers, with bits set according to which indices of pure sets they do and do not contain.

For example, the empty set contains no sets, so it has no 1 bits, and its index is \$ 0 \$.

For the set `{{}}`, it contains only one item, the empty set, which has index 0, so we set a 1 bit in the 0th position: \$ 1 \$.

For the set `{{}, {{}}}`, it contains two items: the empty set with index 0, and the previous `{{}}` which has index 1. Therefore, we set the 0th and 1st bits: \$ 11_2 = 3_{10} \$

My program does the reverse of this process.

This is essentially the same as [my answer to Output every sublist ... eventually](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241143) but operating recursively on itself.

Comment: damn that was fast, by my calculations you posted this within 15 seconds of the question being posted

Comment: @des54321 We had a FGITW shootout: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61382759#61382759

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

Port of [pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248716/64121).

```
{o'&|2\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rOV1erMYqpqOXiSsstsarWUKpW0lHSUVDSz1ev0NRRqlWq5UowsKoGSiqkKVTUqisoGhkAALvmD1U=)

`|2\x` The argument converted to binary, reversed.
`&` Where, indices of 1s.
`o'` For each of those indices, call the function recursively.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

-1 thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248715/enumerate-all-pure-sets#comment555783_248717)

```python
f=lambda x,n=0:x*[1]and x%2*[f(n)]+f(x/2,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAc71iL4GmkHoMeol4MGxrodYQD/Z6m3m/emV2veN2x2dPEZrmzaxt9jZETtAmN3sULINC0RanWVnZMRcgIIYS@TyENcbIdRzeQlyBNAqS/Qc)

A worse version of [pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248716). The input's binary digits encode which sets are included.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, <del>113</del> 79 bytes

*-34 bytes thanks to @alephalpha*

```rs
struct K(Vec<K>);fn f(x:u64)->K{K((0..x).filter(|v|x>>v&1>0).map(f).collect())}
```

Could save 2 bytes by using `u8` instead but then it generates only 5 numbers before overlow. You could also use 128 bit integers to get more numbers. Algorithm copied from @pxeger.

Try it yourself: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1dbb90a9b8347a6cd554723dedbb93e1

Comment: A really clever way to do recursion! But it's shorter to define a function instead of a closure: `struct K(Vec<K>);fn f(x:u64)->K{K((0..x).filter(|v|x>>v&1>0).map(f).collect())}`

Comment: @alephalpha thanks, I was so convinced lambdas where shorter that I never considered their disadvantages

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÝæΔDè}Iè
```

Outputs the 0-based \$n^{th}\$ value.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NzDy85NcTm8otbz8Ir//00B) or [verify the first few test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f/Dcw8vOzfF5fCKWs/DK/7rcIFkudLyixQyFTLzFKoN9PQMDWq5UvK5FBT08wtK9CHmQCk0o20UVDKBSvNS/xtwGXIZcRlzmXCZcgEA).

Outputting the first \$n\$ values would be 8 bytes as well by replacing the `è` with `£`:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NzDy85NcTm8otbz0OL//00B) or [verify the first few test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f/Dcw8vOzfF5fCKWs9Di//rcIFkudLyixQyFTLzFKoN9PQMDWq5UvK5FBT08wtK9CHmQCk0o20UVDKBSvNS/xtwGXIZcRlzmXCZcgEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý         # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
 æ        # Get the powerset of this list
  Δ  }    # Loop until the result no longer changes:
   D      #  Duplicate the list
    è     #  And index each inner-most integers into itself
      I   # After the loop: push the input-integer again
       è  # And index it into the list
       £  # Or alternatively leave that meany leading items from the list
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[Try `∞<æ` online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8m8PL/v8HAA) to see (the infinite version of) the list it uses to reduce all inner integers down to `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

## BQN, 20 bytes

```
{¨(2|·⌊÷2⊸⋆)¨⊸/↕}
```

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge/CdlYrCqCgyfMK34oyK8J2VqcO3MuKKuOKLhinCqOKKuC/ihpXwnZWpfQoo4oCiU2hvdyDigKJSZXBy4oiYRinCqCDihpUxMDA=)

Based on [pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248716/64121).

### Explanation

- `↕` range from 0 to input `x`
- `(...)¨⊸/` filter range over predicate...
- `2|·⌊÷2⊸⋆` equivalent to `floor(x / 2^i) mod 2`
- `S¨` recurse on each filtered index.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code, 28 bytes

```
B0 7B AA EB 0B 0F B3 C6 56 96 E8 F1 FF FF FF 5E 0F BC C6 75 F0 B0 7D AA C6 07 00 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFNb9MwGD77/RUPmao5NJtKBxzadQcQR6Rp2gHU9eA4duLJcaI4HSlV//oyO8DGxR/P52tZXpRSjqPwNTjuEk6XpW1yYaFJr1jdPEHYDOfHc2K@b3xO7LFukZNYsbzvoLzJoMRArN37Cp03xAZZlRHLIktMChvTWNu0E58Hp9f/CR7dbwh66zq9dUXsy8/7b7i9v8O2K8wuw4JYp3pKE6RrempMAc1lJbr38BmM6@ECTmfGSbsvFK59X5jmsrohimQtjOMpHcNcwYNO@b3tt58@LHdrYrrpwKcIbLBYh@16g6tlOMznKbFgYpr/sWRTDWNtF/SaJzOzwsw/uCQQ2d/YKDjRq@TBfReyMk5BNoVaJZGOZUMsy3AI16LB8Z8cs8XyR4g7bDjfO29KpwpMD011uh3m8126PuFXZawCP@BdCBm@XsXQ1wQ@M8gPvfLpNNgQyNM4PkttRenHi/rzx7CEr98EvbIv)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI an address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string, and takes the input number in ESI.

This uses the same method as most other answers, with a set's number having 1s in binary positions corresponding to its elements' numbers.

In assembly:

```
f:  mov al, '{'
    stosb
    jmp b
a:  btr esi, eax
    push rsi
    xchg eax, esi
    call f
    pop rsi
b:  bsf eax, esi
    jnz a
    mov al, '}'
    stosb
    mov BYTE PTR [rdi], 0
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
BṚT’ß€
```

A recursive mondaic Link that accepts `n` (0-indexed) and yields the `n`-th pure set using the empty list as the empty set.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//QuG5mlTigJnDn@KCrP/Dh8WS4bmY//8w)**

#### How?

```
BṚT’ß€ - Link: non-negative integer, n
B      - convert to binary
 Ṛ     - reverse
  T    - truthy indices (1-indexed)
   ’   - decrement (vectorises)
     € - for each:
    ß  -   call this Link
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 49 bytes

Outputs as a lazily evaluated infinite list. Each entry is encoded as a nested list.

```
import Data.List
data P=P[P]
p=P<$>subsequences p
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
λbṘTvx
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQQSIsIiIsIs67YuG5mFR2eCIsIiIsIjBcbjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjUiXQ==)

Port of Jelly.

```
λbṘTvx
λ      # Open a lambda for recursion, f(x)
 b     # Get the binary representation of x (as a list)
  Ṙ    # Reverse
   T   # Get truthy indices of that (zero-indexed)
    vx # For each, recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υΦυ＆ιＸ²λ⭆¹⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTIaC0OEOjVEfBLTOnBCgCZDlllpRnFqc65qVoZOooBOSXA4WNdBRyNIHAmiugKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBiClBRolIIk//@3/K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the 1-indexed `n`th set using `[]`s. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
⊞υΦυ＆ιＸ²λ
```

Extract the existing lists given by the binary decomposition of the current index and push the resulting list to the predefine empty list.

```
⭆¹⊟υ
```

Pretty-print the last list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 53 bytes

```
{`\d+
{$&*_}
+`(_+)\1
$1@
_(?=((@)|(_))*)
$#2$.3*,
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgEAXA/l1DNLtgjOC/MNJ5CRIw0cLGwtihZ8eZ@3jOa9MppzWkGNyuEEUh/QcVyCt2GkJbeFpmIssveWbJEJkRVSNLWKRUQ8OgQYsOPQaMmH4) Link includes test cases. Output's the 0-indexed `n`th set. Explanation:

```
{`
```

Repeat until all subsets have been constructed.

```
\d+
{$&*_}
```

Convert all integers to unary, and wrap them in `{}`s. Note that if the integer was `0`, there were no `_`s, so processing stops for this integer here.

```
+`(_+)\1
$1@
```

Partially convert them to binary, but using the "digits" `@_` and `@`. Normally for binary conversion you would then remove the `@`s before `_`s, but we only need the count of "digits", which here is simply the count of `@`s.

```
_(?=((@)|(_))*)
```

For each `1` in the binary representation, calculate its bit position and whether it's the last `1` bit...

```
$#2$.3*,
```

... and replace it with the position and append a `,` if this is not the last `1` bit.

```
@
```

Delete the remaining `@`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{(0...n).select{|x|n[x]>0}.map &f}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vWsNAT08vT1OvODUnNbmkuqaiJi@6ItbOoFYvN7FAQS2t9j9IhaGBJogPki5QSAMqqP0PAA)

Based on pxeger's python answer.

Comment: You can just use `0..n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```
!k=[!i for i=0:k if k&2^i>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxRCgIhEADQf08xO0RoRFh/LrjROaxAyoVJcWUwcE9vEb0DvNc7kT@23odo3UAwLwxk9RiBZojb050mfeuFQ62rbAoscCjJP4LETcM9MF6Y/XrYna8O7YQOlfgdQBn0aIwR8FWYck1Z/qOBlBIhP/sH)

Port of [pxeger's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248716)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,i=0)=>x?[...x&1?[f(i)]:[],...f(x>>1,i+1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctLCsMgEADQfQ9SRrQybms1B5EsQqJlimRKEoK3n3y2D95v2Id1XOi/vWaeskgJ0AwFVCG2Lllr29N1qQCp/p16c0KBFqMzpN1N4h@FFziLp49DRK81qZHnlWu2lb9wZSWCBw)